# Storing pixels values from 50 images inside a vector

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I need to extract features from specific points from an image. Currently im doing it for one image, but its to much work to go manually from frame to frame. To extract simple pixel intensity levels, im doing this:

```
print(img[45, 80]) 
print(img[45, 100]) 
print(img[50, 65]) 
print(img[50, 110])
print(img[40, 110])
print(img[35, 90])
print(img[25, 90]) 
print(img[25, 110]) 
print(img[64, 89]) 
print(img[25, 65]) 
print(img[40, 65]) 
print(img[65, 60]) 
print(img[65, 120]) 
print(img[82, 75]) 
print(img[82, 105]) 
print(img[78, 88]) 
print(img[110, 90])
print(img[90, 89]) 
print(img[100, 65]) 
print(img[100, 110])

values = [245, 247, 199, 199, 210, 213, 216, 196, 225, 199, 189, 189, 195, 221, 225, 201, 221, 201, 216, 222]
new_values = np.reshape(values,(20,1))
```

Basically, i manually verify the pixels that are more useful to my application and store them inside a vector. Though, those coordinates are constant for all face images, what i want to do then, is to be able to load all 50 images at once, and print their values or/and store them inside a vector.

I am currently loading the images like this:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)


    return loadedImages


imgs = loadImages('C:/Dataset/Frames/')

for img in imgs: 
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    print(img[45, 100])
    plt.show()
```

Not only, it does not work, it also gives me the error:

> TypeError: 'TiffImageFile' object is not

subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to replace `print(img[45, 100])` with `print(img.getpixel((45, 100)))`

Reference: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html